# How to get column value of join query in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssrs-2012

I have select join query for generating report in SSRS. Query is working fine in SQL Server but as I add same query as dataset in SSRS and try to get rows count using CountRows() function it always return 0 (Zero). I'm not getting where my query is going wrong.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT  PR.NAME 
FROm innovator.PROJECT PR
INNER JOIN innovator.PROJECT_RISK LPR ON LPR.SOURCE_ID = Pr.ID
INNER JOIN innovator.RISK_MANAGEMENT LR ON LR.id = LPR.RELATED_ID
Inner join innovator.PROGRAM_PROJECT P ON PR.ID  = P.RELATED_ID 
Inner Join innovator.PROGRAM PP ON P.SOURCE_ID = PP.ID
WHERE  pp.ID = @Id
```

**Fetching total count using CountRows() for Textbox**

```
=CountRows(Fields!NAME.Value, "DataSetRisk")
```

DataSetRisk is Dataset name and Name is column name of Project Table

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CountRows function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156330%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). For example

```
=CountRows("MyDataset")

Example : =CountRows("DataSetRisk")
```

will give you the number of rows in MyDataSet.

Comment: @Gaurav Try after avoiding Field name in your syntax like `=CountRows("DataSetRisk")`

Comment: I tried your above suggestion, but still there no change

Answer (score 0):

Try something a little simpler: `Count(Fields!NAME.Value)` as a column.  This assumes, of course, that field name actually is populated.  If the column is in separate groups, it will provide a count for each group, otherwise it will count for the entire report.

Comment: Sorry to say but this solution is also not working. I think there is some issue in getting alias name from query. Because if I use single table query and try to retrieve value its working fine but only with join query where alias is used its not working

Comment: Can you post your rdl?  Something is in disconnect if none of the provided ideas (including your own) return a value other than 0.  The SQL JOIN data, by the time it gets consumed by the rdl, is a single entity, so SSRS wise, not pertinent to the issue.  Unless, of course, your SQL provides no rows, in which case you have a data issue and any method of counting rows is going to return 0.